# Can I go without using "that" in this type of sentences?

Tags: that

Example sentences:

**You can only see pictures [that] they have picked.**

**I've got those letters [that] she sent me.**

I don't like "that", but without it it feels like something is missing.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why you don't like '_that_'. In any case, there was a recent similar question about the omission of objective _that_ in relative clauses: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/434051/relative-clauses-to-use-or-not-to-use-that

Answer (score 0):

It's ok for me if you add "the". It helps make it clearer and define what you are talking about :

You can only see **the** pictures [that] they have picked.

I've got **the** letters [that] she sent me.

Comment: Adding 'the' in the first example changes the meaning to 'all the pictures'.

Comment: Don't think so. And if you wanna add "[that] they have picked", it's the most natural way it sounds for me.